# Select Same Customer Name but that has different customer Address

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Trying to select records that are all for the same customer, but where the address is different.

So I can later let the user choose Bob Yonkers, then choose to update all of Bob's records to a specific address.  So I want to show all the available records.

**Data Example:**

```
CUSTOMER_NAME, CUSTOMER_ADDRESS
Bob Yonkers  , 42 Satellite Cir
Bob Yonkers  , 667 Orbit St
Bob Yonkers  , 42 Satellite Cir
Bob Yonkers  , 667 Orbit St
David Boom   , 5959 Bush Ave
David Boom   , 5959 Bush Ave
David Boom   , 5959 Bush Ave
David Boom   , 5959 Bush Ave
David Boom   , 5959 Bush Ave
Ruby Tuesday , 123 Highway Ln Apt#1
Ruby Tuesday , 123 Highway Ln
David Boom   ,5959 Bush Ave
David Boom   ,5959 Bush Ave
David Boom   ,5959 Bush Ave
```

So the query would bring back these results...

**Result Example:**

```
CUSTOMER_NAME, CUSTOMER_ADDRESS
Bob Yonkers  , 42 Satellite Cir
Bob Yonkers  , 667 Orbit St
Ruby Tuesday , 123 Highway Ln Apt#1
Ruby Tuesday , 123 Highway Ln
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Reading your question it seems like the question you've *asked* isn't the question you *want.* It reads as if you want to find addresses that have multiple customers resident at that address. Could you clarify a little?

Comment: please, post the structure of the related tables

Comment: Hope that helps, didn't realize how bad it was formatted before

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a refinement of Joel's:

```
SELECT distinct t1.* 
FROM [table] t1
INNER JOIN [table] t2 ON t1.Name=t2.Name AND t1.Address<>t2.Address
```

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT * 
FROM [table] t1
INNER JOIN [table] t2 ON t1.Name=t2.Name AND t1.Address<>t2.Address
```

Comment: I think you need a SELECT DISTINCT, otherwise you'll get repetitions in the example case.

Comment: This one is close, but it brings back all four of Bob Yonkers, instead of just the two different addresses.

Answer (score 0):

give this a try...

```
select * from (select count(customername) as ct, customername, address from table group by customername, address) t1
where t1.ct>1
```

Answer (score 0):

This intrigued me since a friend had asked me something similar. The query below will solve the problem, albeit in-efficiently:

`mysql> select DISTINCT CUSTOMER_NAME,CUSTOMER_ADDRESS from CUST_ADDR
where CUSTOMER_NAME in (select CUSTOMER_NAME from CUST_ADDR GROUP BY 
CUSTOMER_NAME HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CUSTOMER_ADDRESS) > 1 );`

```
+---------------+----------------------+
| CUSTOMER_NAME | CUSTOMER_ADDRESS     |
+---------------+----------------------+
| Bob Yonkers   | 42 Satellite Cir     |
| Bob Yonkers   | 667 Orbit St         |
| Ruby Tuesday  | 123 Highway Ln Apt#1 |
| Ruby Tuesday  | 123 Highway Ln       |
+---------------+----------------------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```